Likelihood ratios not distributed as a chi2 distribution with the correct dof (Wilk's theorem)
I perform Bayesian inference on a mixture model such that, μ is the mixture weight for a feature in the mixture
p(x|μ,theta) = μ p_feature(x|theta) + (1-μ) p_nofeature(x|theta).
I calculate T(μ) = \log( p(x|μ=0, theta(μ=0)) | p(x | μ*, theta*), where x is fixed, where
theta(μ=0) = \arg max_theta p(x | μ=0, theta)  (null hypothesis)
μ*, theta* = \arg max_{μ,theta) p(x | μ, theta)
I donot have access to the likelihood, so I find the two solutions above by maximzing the p(μ, theta|x) / p(μ, theta), which is the same as p(x | μ, theta) / p(x).
I calculate the LLR statistic for several x by sampling from the prior of theta as x= f(μ, theta). https://towardsdatascience.com/the-likelihood-ratio-test-463455b34de9 tells me that I should obtain a chi2 distribution with a dof being the difference between the model parameters of the whole model- null hypothesis. However, this is what I obtain for two separate models with dof 6.


I get a chi2 of degrees of freedom 19 and almost a uniform distribution for the second model. I would expect a chi2 of degree of freedom 6. What am i missing?

Interesting question, however, it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com instead.
